# Error when shifting from tf.TFRecordReader() to tf.data.TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I am playing around the method about tfRecord to speed up my training. The code I have for reading `.tfrecord` is as follows

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
filenameQueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['train.tfrecords'])

_, serializedExample = reader.read(filenameQueue)

features = tf.io.parse_single_example(
                                   serializedExample,
                                   features = {
                                   'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                   'boxes': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
                                   })

image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'],tf.uint8)
boxes = tf.decode_raw(features['boxes'],tf.float32)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess, coord=coord)

for i in range(3):
    _, Box = sess.run([image,boxes])
print(Box)
```

This works good, except I was keeping get information that I need to use `tf.data.Dataset` to replace `reader`. I am trying to do it by replace the first three lines of above code to

```
serializedExample = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tf.gfile.Glob(['train.tfrecord']))
```

Then, I start to get error like

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.readers.TFRecordDatasetV1'> to Tensor. Contents: <TFRecordDatasetV1 shapes: (), types: tf.string>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

I tried several tips that I searched online but did not get lucky so far. Probably I missed sth simple...